# Drag and Drop with Angular JS and JQuery

Tags: jquery-ui, angularjs-directive

Couple of days ago I found this interesting post at http://www.smartjava.org/content/drag-and-drop-angularjs-using-jquery-ui 
 and applied it into my website. However when I progressively using it there is a bug I identified, basically you can not move an item directly from one div to another's bottom, it has to go through the parts above and progress to the bottom. Anyone can suggest where does it goes wrong? The example is at http://www.smartjava.org/examples/dnd/double.html

Troubling me for days already.....

Comment: Oh, waited for so long and no one even looked at it.....

Answer (score 0):

I did this a bit differently. Instead of attaching a jquery ui element inside the directive's controller, I instead did it inside the directive's link function. I came up with my solution, based on a [blog post](http://www.benfarrell.com/2013/03/30/drag-and-drop-with-angularjs-and-jquery-ui/) by Ben Farrell.

Note, that this is a `Rails` app, and I am using the `acts_as_list` gem to calculate positioning.

```
 app.directive('sortable', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elt, attrs) {

      // the card that will be moved
      scope.movedCard = {};
      return elt.sortable({
        connectWith: ".deck",
        revert: true,
        items: '.card',
        stop: function(evt, ui) {
          return scope.$apply(function() {

            // the deck the card is being moved to
            // deck-id is an element attribute I defined
            scope.movedCard.toDeck = parseInt(ui.item[0].parentElement.attributes['deck-id'].value);

            // the id of the card being moved
            // the card id is an attribute I definied
            scope.movedCard.id = parseInt(ui.item[0].attributes['card-id'].value);

            // edge case that handles a card being added to the end of the list
            if (ui.item[0].nextElementSibling !== null) {
              scope.movedCard.pos = parseInt(ui.item[0].nextElementSibling.attributes['card-pos'].value - 1);
            } else {
              // the card is being added to the very end of the list
              scope.movedCard.pos = parseInt(ui.item[0].previousElementSibling.attributes['card-pos'].value + 1);
            }

            // broadcast to child scopes the movedCard event
            return scope.$broadcast('movedCardEvent', scope.movedCard);
          });
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

### Important points

- I utilize card attributes to store a card's id, deck, and position, in order to allow the `jQuery sortable` widget to grab onto.
- After the `stop` event is called, I immediately execute a `scope.$apply` function to get back into, what Misko Hevery call,s the `angular execution context`.
- I have a working example of this in action, up in a [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/KurtRMueller/SmartDeck) of mine.